# Движение игрока по определенному слою

Tags: unity3d

Задался вопросом, как ограничить передвижение игрока в рамках одного слоя, чтобы при столкновении с краем слоя, игрок упирался в него? Есть идеи?

Comment: слой - это обьект? допустим пол?

Comment: Делаешь каст луча/сферы/чего угодно, указывая в параметрах нужный слой, если столкновений нет, то не двигаешь персонажа, если есть двигаешь

Comment: @bfgquaka да, пол

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть отдельная настройка **физических слов**   Edit->ProjectSettings->Physics

Нас интересует место с **пересечением слоев**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я оставил галочки только для слоя Default. Значит при физической симуляции слой Default будет взаимодействовать **только с самим собой**. Объекты из другого слоя не будут взаимодействовать с Default.

Дальше я думаю вы поймете принцип работы.